# Printing the max and max index within a range in a list

Tags: python, list, random, indexing, range

In the code below it randomly selects a range of numbers within the `list_`. Stop has to be greater than start, and than I want the program to output the maximum number within the `list_[start:stop]` as well as the order that number is at. I am having an issue printing the index of the functions between a range in the `list_`.

```
#15 numbers in the list
list_ = [1,3,5,6,7,2,3,6,4,3,5,7,8,11,10]
stop= random.randint(1, len(list_))
start = random.randint(0, stop)

maxnum = max(list_[start:stop])
max_index = list_.index(maxnum)
print("maximum number in range: ", maxnum, "index of max number: ", max_index)
```

Comment: What is the expected and actual output of this? You can use a seeded random number generator to make it reproducible, `random.seed(42)`.

Comment: I will update it now

Comment: What is exactly your problem? I executed this code with no problem at all.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you have repeated number in `list_`.  The `.index` method returns the index of the **first** instance of that it finds.  If `start=5` and `stop=7`, the max is `3` at index `6`.  But the returned index is `1` because you are finding the first 3 in the entire list.

You can get around this by using `index` on your sublist, then adding the `start` index.  Though if there are repeats of the max value in your sublist, it will again return the first index.

```
max_index = list_[start:stop].index(maxnum) + start
```

Comment: it gives me a type error of rangeindex object is not callable

Answer (score 0):

Another (slightly more concise) way is to use `start` and `stop` parameters of the `index` method:

```
max_index = list_.index(maxnum, start, stop)
```